# Does log4r also possible security vulnerabilities like that if log4j

Tags: r, log4j

Does log4r also possess security vulnerabilities like log4j. And does log4j security vulnerabilities also affect log4r

Answer (score 1):

This has been addressed by the creator of `log4r` (Aaron Jacobs) on the `log4r` Github page, [here](https://github.com/johnmyleswhite/log4r/issues/21):

> We are in no way affected by that CVE, nor is there an analogous design flaw in this package.

So, the authors do not think so.

Answer (score 0):

A nice place to check for security vulnerabilities in R packages is [Sonatype OSS Index](https://ossindex.sonatype.org/).

They don't find any known vulnerabilities in the current version of `log4r` on CRAN: https://ossindex.sonatype.org/component/pkg:cran/log4r